# select column values as fields from multiple tables in MySQL with customized conditions

Tags: mysql

I am not more familiar with MySQL.i want to select some column fields as values from another table by applying some customized conditions I tried out with some queries but not getting the proper result since it has some inner options. 
please advice me on this

Thanks in advance

please refer to the fiddle.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e7c0ff159f300ed1dc220ca12b10dc2d

Comment: What's the "expected data"?

Comment: @ Rick James Thank your for your reply. my expected out put may like this .  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e7c0ff159f300ed1dc220ca12b10dc2d

Comment: Using row values as column names for other queries isn't a way SQL works. If you're after a general attribute system take a looks at some existing options in [Rick's EAV guide](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav).

Comment: The second part of your desired output is the "un-pivot" of your first table.